# rails post test model error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing

So this is the error I'm getting

.F

Failure:
PostTest#test_post_should_be_valid [/home/ubuntu/workspace/test/models/post_test.rb:9]:
["User must exist"]

I'm not sure what it means by "user must exist" since I'm pretty sure a user with an user_id one does exist.
heres my code

## post_test.rb

```
require 'test_helper'

class PostTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  def setup
    @post=Post.new(user_id: "1",name:"ruby meetup")
  end

  test "post should be valid" do
    assert @post.valid?, @post.errors.full_messages
  end

end
```

## post.rb

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
belongs_to :user
 geocoded_by :address
after_validation :geocode, if: ->(obj){ obj.address.present? and obj.address_changed? }
reverse_geocoded_by :latitude, :longitude
after_validation :reverse_geocode


  has_many :rsvps
  has_many :users, through: :rsvps

  validates :name, presence: true






end
```

I'm not sure if this will be helpful but I'm also going to include my user test and user model.

## user_test.rb

```
require 'test_helper'

class UserTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  def setup
    @user=User.new(email:"fo30@hotmail.com", password: "h3h3123")
  end


  test "user should be valid" do
    assert @user.valid?, @user.errors.full_messages
  end
end
```

## user.rb

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
         has_many :posts

          has_many :rsvps
          has_many :posts, through: :rsvps

          validates :email, presence: true





end
```

Any help will greatly be appreciated as I just recently started testing in rails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`User.new` creates a new user in memory, but not in the database. It won't have a valid `id` to populate `user_id`.

Try `User.create!`.

Next, database records are not shared between test runs. Rails attempts "test isolation" by zilching records after each test case. So your PostTest needs its own copy of `User.create!`.

After you get this working, look up the general topic of "rails test fixtures"...

Comment: Alright so I've done what you said but I'm still getting the same error

Comment: Did you fix `PostTest#index` so it also creates a User, and it assigns that user's `id` to `user_id`?

Comment: Ok so I just had to copy the user_id in my user yml file and everything is now working thank you.